In Common Base Config.(BJT), Why is \$I_e\$ and \$V_{BE}\$ called input characteristics and \$I_C\$ and \$V_{CB}\$ called output characteristic?
I have been following this textbook from Robert Boyelstad called "Electronic Devices and Circuit Theory". While studying about BJT's Common Base Configuration from this text book, I found that Emitter Current and Base Emitter Voltage are known as input parameters and Collector current and Collector Base Voltage are known to be output parameters.
Now, my question is why Emitter current and Base Emitter voltage are input parameters? Can't Collector current and Collector Base Voltage be called input parameters?
Here is the input and output characteristics presented in the textbook.


In the input characteristics above, Base Emitter Voltage is positive and from what I understand, this happens in NPN transistor. Now if I have PNP transistor, Are the input parameters \$I_C\$ and \$V_{BC}\$ and output parameters \$I_E\$ and \$V_{EB}\$? Any help or hint will be appreciated!

Please provide an attempt at a solution


Can't Collector current and Collector Base Voltage be called input
parameters?

If you are talking about a common-base circuit then the input is applied to the emitter and, the output is taken from the collector. Therefore there can be no room for reversing the roles of input and output. In fact, this also applies to common-emitter circuits too (input is base and output is collector).
For common-collector circuits the input is the base and the output is from the emitter.
